# access preferences in live wallpaper

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

i have created a live wallpaper and in that there is a "setting" button which loads PreferenceActivity but without clicking on "settings" but i want to access the SharedPreferences within subclass of Engine or WallpaperService. As i just want to access the small single string so i don;t want user to go into settings and access that string.
So i want to execute this code inside Subclass of Engine or WallpaperSerivce

```
SharedPreferences  mPrefs = getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences();
String option = mPrefs.getString(
this.getResources().getString(R.string.name),
this.getResources().getString(R.string.option));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not the best way to do it I'm sure but I use getters and setters to achieve this effect.

```
private int mySetting = defaultvalue                

public int getMySetting() {
       return mySetting;
}

public void setMySetting(int mySetting) {
       this.mySetting = mySetting;
}
```

I obviously used some plain text in that code but hopefully it is pretty self explanitory

You set this variable while in Settings Class with...

```
Settings.this.setMySetting(value);
```

Remove "this" to call from other classes

You can retieve this information in any of your classes using the following

```
Settings.getMySetting();
```

You can use pretty much any variable type just make sure you define the mySetting variable as that type before trying to pass a value other than int as in this example. Hopefully this helps.